# htaccess is not working as wanted in shopping cart

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Well, I am making a shopping cart system.

I have `.htaccess` file in my root folder containing the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product/([^/.]+)/?$ product.php?code=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^AnotherPage/([^/.]+)/?$ AnotehrPage.php?code=$1 [L]
```

There are some pages that I need to have query strings, for example add to cart page. If they click on add to cart button on the product(s) page, it redirects them like this:

`http://www.example.com/cart.php?action=add&code=ProductCode`

And when the product is added in the cart, I am again redirecting them to the cart.php page where they can see their products added in their cart.

I have also used query string in checkout page for some reason.

Now what I want is, how to write the rules and conditions in `.htaccess` file in order for the query string to work without affecting the SEO functionality and/or SEO URLs.

The SEO friendly URL will work only to the static pages like showing product details, about us, contact us, etc. and the dynamic pages will have query strings.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here's the link that I had tried to solve it, but to no success: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14308411/3514160

**EDIT 1**:
Here's the full htaccess that I have tried so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product/([^/.]+)/?$ product.php?code=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^AnotherPage/([^/.]+)/?$ AnotehrPage.php?code=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=([^&]+) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &code=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^cart\.php/([^/]+/[^/]+)$ http://www.example.com/cart.php/$1/%1/? [R,L]
```

**EDIT 2**:
Product.php page:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

require_once 'Classes/class.Validation.php';
$validate = new Validation('benef8w7_ecommerce');

$code = substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], strrpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/') + 1);
$name = $amount = $desc = $specs = $return = $ship = $tncs = $qnty = "";
$metaKeyWords = $metaDescription = "";
$q = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ProdCode = '".$code."' ";

if ( $validate->Query( $q ) == TRUE ) {
    if ( $validate->NumRows() >= 1 ) {
        while ( $row = $validate->FetchAllDatas() ) {
            $name = $row['ProdName'];
            $amount = $row['ProdRate'];
            $desc = $row['ProdDescription'];
            $specs = $row['ProdSpecifications'];
            $return = $row['ProdReturnCancellation'];
            $ship = $row['ProdShippingDelivery'];
            $tncs = $row['ProdTermsConditions'];
            $qnty = $row['ProdTotalQuantity'];

            $metaKeyWords = $row["ProdMetaKeyWords"];
            $metaDescription = $row["ProdMetaDescription"];
        }
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="ie9" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <title>Benefit Square - Product</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $metaKeyWords; ?>">
    <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $metaDescription; ?>">

    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="//www.benefitsquare.com/nbs/images/bs-favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="//www.benefitsquare.com/nbs/css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="//www.benefitsquare.com/nbs/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="//www.benefitsquare.com/nbs/css/jquery.custom-scrollbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="//www.benefitsquare.com/nbs/css/owl.carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="//www.benefitsquare.com/nbs/css/style.css">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <!--wide layout-->
    <div class="wide_layout relative w_xs_auto">
        <!--markup header-->
        <?php require_once 'Includes/websiteNav.php'; ?>

        <div style="margin-top: -20px;"></div>

        <section class="breadcrumbs wide_layout relative w_xs_auto m_bottom_20">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="horizontal_list clearfix bc_list f_size_medium">
                    <li class="m_right_10 current">
                        <a href="//www.benefitsquare.com/nbs/" class="default_t_color">
                            Home<i class="fa fa-angle-right d_inline_middle m_left_10"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="m_right_10">
                        <a href="//www.benefitsquare.com/nbs/products.php" class="default_t_color">
                            Products<i class="fa fa-angle-right d_inline_middle m_left_10"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <?php echo $name . " - " . $code; ?>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>


        <!--content-->
        <div class="page_content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row clearfix">

                    <section class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 m_xs_bottom_30">
                        <div class="clearfix m_bottom_15 t_xs_align_c">
                            <h2 class="color_dark fw_medium m_bottom_10"><?php echo $name; ?></h2>
                        </div>
                    </section>

                    <!--left content column-->
                    <section class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 m_xs_bottom_30">
                        <div class="clearfix m_bottom_30 t_xs_align_c">
                            <div class="photoframe type_2 shadow r_corners f_left f_sm_none d_xs_inline_b product_single_preview relative m_right_30 m_bottom_5 m_sm_bottom_20 m_xs_right_0 w_mxs_full">
                                <div class="relative d_inline_b m_bottom_10 qv_preview d_xs_block">
                                    <img id="zoom_image" src="//www.benefitsquare.com/nbs/images/Products/<?php echo $code ?>.jpg" data-big="images/Products/<?php echo $code ?>.jpg" class="tr_all_hover" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" height="438" width="438">
                                    <a href="//www.benefitsquare.com/nbs/images/Products/<?php echo $code; ?>.jpg" class="d_block button_type_5 r_corners tr_all_hover box_s_none color_light p_hr_0">
                                        <i class="fa fa-expand"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <!--carousel-->
                                <!-- <div class="relative qv_carousel_wrap">
                                    <button class="button_type_11 bg_light_color_1 t_align_c f_size_ex_large bg_cs_hover r_corners d_inline_middle bg_tr tr_all_hover qv_btn_single_prev">
                                        <i class="fa fa-angle-left "></i>
                                    </button>
                                    <ul class="qv_carousel_single d_inline_middle maddy">
                                        <a href="#" data-image="images/Products/<?php echo $code ?>.jpg" data-zoom-image="images/Products/<?php echo $code ?>.jpg">
                                            <img src="images/Products/<?php echo $code ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" height="110" width="110">
                                        </a>

                                        <a href="#" data-image="images/Products/<?php echo $code ?>.jpg" data-zoom-image="images/Products/<?php echo $code ?>.jpg">
                                            <img src="images/Products/<?php echo $code ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" height="110" width="110">
                                        </a>

                                        <a href="#" data-image="images/Products/<?php echo $code ?>.jpg" data-zoom-image="images/Products/<?php echo $code ?>.jpg">
                                            <img src="images/Products/<?php echo $code ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" height="110" width="110">
                                        </a>

                                        <a href="#" data-image="images/Products/<?php echo $code ?>.jpg" data-zoom-image="images/Products/<?php echo $code ?>.jpg">
                                            <img src="images/Products/<?php echo $code ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" height="110" width="110">
                                        </a>

                                        <a href="#" data-image="images/Products/<?php echo $code ?>.jpg" data-zoom-image="images/Products/<?php echo $code ?>.jpg">
                                            <img src="images/Products/<?php echo $code ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" height="110" width="110">
                                        </a>

                                        <a href="#" data-image="images/Products/<?php echo $code ?>.jpg" data-zoom-image="images/Products/<?php echo $code ?>.jpg">
                                            <img src="images/Products/<?php echo $code ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" height="110" width="110">
                                        </a>

                                    </ul>
                                    <button class="button_type_11 bg_light_color_1 t_align_c f_size_ex_large bg_cs_hover r_corners d_inline_middle bg_tr tr_all_hover qv_btn_single_next">
                                        <i class="fa fa-angle-right "></i>
                                    </button>
                                </div> -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="p_top_10 t_xs_align_l">
                                <!--description-->
                                <!-- <h2 class="color_dark fw_medium m_bottom_10"><?php echo $name; ?></h2> -->

                                <hr class="m_bottom_10 divider_type_3">
                                <table class="description_table m_bottom_10">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Availability:</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php if($qnty >= 1): ?>
                                                <span class="color_green">in stock</span> <?php echo $qnty . ' items(s)'; ?>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Product Code:</td>
                                        <td><?php echo $code; ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <hr class="divider_type_3 m_bottom_10">
                                <p class="m_bottom_10"><?php echo $desc; ?></p>
                                <hr class="divider_type_3 m_bottom_15">
                                <div class="m_bottom_15">
                                    <span class="v_align_b f_size_big m_left_5 scheme_color fw_medium">Rs.: <?php echo $amount; ?></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="m_bottom_20">
                                    <!-- <a href="cart.php?action=add&code=<?php //echo $code; ?>" class="button_type_12 r_corners bg_scheme_color color_light tr_delay_hover d_inline_b f_size_large">Add to Cart</a> -->
                                    <a href="http://www.benefitsquare.com/nbs/cart/add/<?php echo $code; ?>" class="button_type_4 bg_scheme_color r_corners tr_all_hover color_light mw_0 m_bottom_15">Add to Cart</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--tabs-->
                        <div class="accordion m_bottom_45">
                            <?php if (!empty($specs)): ?>
                                <div class="accordion_item r_corners shadow wrapper m_bottom_5">
                                    <h3 class="color_light active a_title relative tr_all_hover">
                                        Specifications
                                        <span class="minus_icon tr_all_hover">-</span>
                                        <span class="plus_icon tr_all_hover">+</span>
                                    </h3>
                                    <div class="bg_light_color_3 a_content">
                                        <p class="m_bottom_10">
                                            <?php echo $specs; ?>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if (!empty($return)): ?>
                                <div class="accordion_item r_corners shadow wrapper m_bottom_5">
                                    <h3 class="bg_light_color_1 color_dark a_title relative tr_all_hover">
                                        Return And Cancellation
                                        <span class="minus_icon tr_all_hover">-</span>
                                        <span class="plus_icon tr_all_hover">+</span>
                                    </h3>
                                    <div class="bg_light_color_3 a_content">
                                        <p class="m_bottom_10">
                                            <?php echo $return; ?>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if (!empty($ship)): ?>
                                <div class="accordion_item r_corners shadow wrapper m_bottom_5">
                                    <h3 class="bg_light_color_1 color_dark a_title relative tr_all_hover">
                                        Shipping
                                        <span class="minus_icon tr_all_hover">-</span>
                                        <span class="plus_icon tr_all_hover">+</span>
                                    </h3>
                                    <div class="bg_light_color_3 a_content">
                                        <p class="m_bottom_10">
                                            <?php echo $ship; ?>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if (!empty($tncs)): ?>
                                <div class="accordion_item r_corners shadow wrapper m_bottom_5">
                                    <h3 class="bg_light_color_1 color_dark a_title relative tr_all_hover">
                                        Terms And Conditions
                                        <span class="minus_icon tr_all_hover">-</span>
                                        <span class="plus_icon tr_all_hover">+</span>
                                    </h3>
                                    <div class="bg_light_color_3 a_content">
                                        <p class="m_bottom_10">
                                            <?php echo $tncs; ?>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                        <hr class="divider_type_3 m_bottom_15">
                    </section>

                    <!--right column-->
                    <aside class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                        <?php
                        $q = "SELECT p.*, b.* FROM products p, beneficiaries b WHERE p.BenCode = b.BenCode AND p.ProdCode = '".$code."'";
                        $validate->Query($q);
                        if ($validate->NumRows() >= 1) {
                            while ($row = $validate->FetchAllDatas()) {
                                $fileName = $row["BenCode"].".jpg";
                                $filePath = "http://www.benefitsquare.com/nbs/images/Beneficiary/".$fileName;
                                $msg = "The File Does not exts";
                                echo '
                                <figure class="widget shadow r_corners wrapper m_bottom_15">
                                    <figcaption>
                                        <h3 class="color_light t_align_c">About Beneficiary</h3>
                                    </figcaption>
                                    <div class="widget_content t_align_c">
                                        <div class="circle wrapper team_photo d_inline_b m_bottom_15">';

                                            if ( @getimagesize($filePath)) {                                                
                                                echo '<img src="//www.benefitsquare.com/nbs/images/Beneficiary/'.$row["BenCode"].'.jpg" alt="'.$row["BenFullName"].'">';
                                            } else {
                                                echo '<img src="//placehold.it/200x200" alt="">';
                                            }
                                            echo '
                                        </div>
                                        <h4 class="fw_medium color_dark">
                                            <a href="beneficiary.php?code='.$row["BenCode"].'" class="color_dark">'.$row["BenFullName"].'</a>
                                        </h4>
                                        <p class="color_dark m_bottom_10">'.$row["BenCode"].'</p>
                                        <p class="color_dark m_bottom_10">'.$row["BenCity"].', '.$row["BenState"].', '.$row["BenCountry"].'</p>
                                    </div>
                                </figure>
                                ';
                            }
                        }
                        ?>

                        <?php require_once 'PHP_Includes/CategoriesWidget.php'; ?>

                        <!--tags-->
                        <figure class="widget shadow r_corners wrapper m_bottom_30">
                            <figcaption>
                                <h3 class="color_light">Tags</h3>
                            </figcaption>

                            </div>
                        </figure>
                    </aside>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--markup footer-->
        <?php require_once 'Includes/websiteFooter.php'; ?>
    </div>

    <!--login popup-->
    <?php require_once 'Includes/CustomerLogin.php'; ?>

    <!--login popup-->
    <?php require_once 'Includes/CustomerRegistration.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

cart.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

require_once 'Classes/class.Validation.php';
$validate = new Validation('benef8w7_ecommerce');

$code = "";
$sesionAmount = 0;
$amount = 0;

$code = substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], strrpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/') + 1);

if ( (isset($_GET["action"]) && $_GET["action"] == "add" ) && (isset($_GET["code"]) && $_GET["code"] != "" ) ) {
    if ( isset( $_SESSION['cart'][$code] ) && $_SESSION['cart'][$code] != "" ) {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$code]['quantity']++;
    } else {
        $q = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ProdCode = '".$code."' ";
        $validate->Query( $q );
        if ( $validate->NumRows() >= 1 ) {
            while ( $row = $validate->FetchAllDatas() ) {
                $_SESSION['cart'][$row['ProdCode']] = array(
                    "quantity" => 1,
                    "rate" => $row['ProdRate']
                    );
                $_SESSION['cartAmt'] = $row['ProdRate'] * $_SESSION['cart'][$row['ProdCode']]['quantity'];
            }
        } else {
            echo '<br />No product fetched.<br />';
        }
    }
}



if ( isset( $_POST['btnSubmit'] ) ) {
    foreach ( $_POST['qnty'] as $key => $value ) {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['quantity'] = $value;
        header("Location: cart.php");
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="ie9" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <title>Benefit Sqaure - Cart</title>

    <!-- Meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="//www.benefitsquare.com/nbs/images/bs-favicon.png">

    <!--stylesheet include-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="//www.benefitsquare.com/nbs/css/flexslider.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="//www.benefitsquare.com/nbs/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="//www.benefitsquare.com/nbs/css/owl.carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="//www.benefitsquare.com/nbs/css/owl.transitions.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="//www.benefitsquare.com/nbs/css/jquery.custom-scrollbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="//www.benefitsquare.com/nbs/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="//www.benefitsquare.com/nbs/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="//www.benefitsquare.com/nbs/StyleSheets/toastr.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        .ShowProds {
            display: none;
        }

        .ShowProds ul {
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }

        .ShowProds ul li {
            background: #fff;
            padding: 5px;
            border-bottom: 1px #eee solid;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!--boxed layout-->
    <div class="wide_layout relative w_xs_auto">
        <?php require_once 'Includes/websiteNav.php'; ?>

        <div class="page_content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row clearfix">
                    <section class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 m_xs_bottom_30">
                        <h2 class="tt_uppercase color_dark m_bottom_25">Cart</h2>
                        <table class="table_type_4 responsive_table full_width r_corners wraper shadow t_align_l t_xs_align_c m_bottom_30">
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="f_size_large">
                                    <th>Product Image &amp; Name</th>
                                    <th>Product Code</th>
                                    <th>Price</th>
                                    <th>Quantity</th>
                                    <th>Subtotal</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <?php
                                    if ( isset( $_SESSION['cart'] ) && is_array( $_SESSION['cart'] ) && sizeOf( $_SESSION['cart'] ) > 0 ) {
                                        $total = 0;
                                        $subTotal = 0; $sbTotal = 0;
                                        $taxAmount = $tax = $totalTaxAmount = $taxAmt = 0;
                                        $cartWeightPerProduct = $totalCartWeight = $amtWeight = 0;

                                        $sql = "SELECT p.*, c.*, ws.* FROM products p, categories c, weight_shipping ws WHERE p.ProdCode IN (";
                                            foreach ( $_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value ) {
                                                $sql .= '"'.$id.'",';
                                            }
                                            $sql = substr( $sql, 0, -1 ) . ") AND p.CatId = c.CatId AND ws.ProdId = p.ProdId";

if ($validate->Query($sql) == TRUE) {
    if ($validate->NumRows() >= 1) {
        while ( $row = $validate->FetchAllDatas() ) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td data-title="Product Image &amp; name" class="t_md_align_c"><img src="images/Products/'.$row['ProdCode'].'.jpg" alt="'.$row['ProdCode'].'" class="m_md_bottom_5 d_xs_block d_xs_centered" height="75" width="75"><a href="product.php?code='.$row['ProdCode'].'" class="d_inline_b m_left_5 color_dark">'.$row['ProdName'].'</a></td>';
            echo '<td data-title="SKU">'.$row['ProdCode'].'</td>';
            echo '<td data-title="Price"><p class="f_size_large color_dark">Rs. '.$row['ProdRate'].'</p></td>';
            echo '<td data-title="Quantity"><div class="clearfix quantity r_corners d_inline_middle f_size_medium color_dark m_bottom_10"><form action="cart.php" method="POST"><input type="number" max="99" min="0" name="qnty['.$row["ProdCode"].']" value="'.$_SESSION['cart'][$row['ProdCode']]['quantity'].'" class="f_left"><br /><button type="submit" name="btnSubmit" class="f_left"><span class="fa fa-refresh"></span></button></form><form action="removeProduct.php" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="remove['.$row["ProdCode"].']" value="'.($row['ProdRate'] * $_SESSION['cart'][$row['ProdCode']]['quantity']).'"><button type="submit" name="btnRemove" class="f_right"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></button></form></div></td>';
            $sbTotal = $row['ProdRate'] * $_SESSION['cart'][$row['ProdCode']]['quantity'];
            $subTotal = $sbTotal;
            echo '<td data-title="Subtotal"><p class="f_size_large fw_medium scheme_color t_align_r">'.number_format($sbTotal, 2).'</p></td>';
            $total += $subTotal;
            $_SESSION['cartTotalAmount'] = $total;
            $tax = $row['CatTaxPercent'];
            $taxAmt = (($sbTotal * $tax ) / 100);
            $taxAmount += $taxAmt;
            $amt = 0;
            $cartWeightPerProduct = ($row['weight'] * $_SESSION['cart'][$row['ProdCode']]['quantity']);
            echo '</tr>';
            $totalCartWeight += $cartWeightPerProduct;
        }
        $totalTaxAmount += $taxAmount;

        $_SESSION['cartWeight'] = $totalCartWeight;

        if ( isset( $_SESSION['credits'] ) && $_SESSION['credits'] != "" ) {
            $cred = number_format( $_SESSION['credits'], 2 );           
        } else {
            $cred = number_format( 0, 2 );
        }

        $_SESSION['sessionTotalPayable'] = ( ($total + $totalTaxAmount) - $cred );
        //$_SESSION['Presentation']['TotalPayableAmount'] = number_format($_SESSION['sessionTotalPayable'], 2);
        $_SESSION['Presentation']['TotalPayableAmount'] = ( ($total + $totalTaxAmount) - $cred );
        if ( isset( $_SESSION['sessionTotalPayable'] ) ) {
            $amt = $_SESSION['sessionTotalPayable'];
        } else {
            $amt = "Rs. 0";
        }

        echo '<tr><td colspan="4"><p class="fw_medium f_size_large t_align_r t_xs_align_c">Cart Total:</p></td><td colspan="1"><p class="fw_medium f_size_large color_dark t_align_r">'.number_format($total, 2).'</p></td></tr>';

        echo '<tr><td colspan="4"><p class="f_size_large t_align_r t_xs_align_c">Taxes:</p></td><td colspan="1"><p class="f_size_large color_dark t_align_r">'. number_format($totalTaxAmount, 2) .'</p></td></tr>';

        echo '<tr><td colspan="4"><p class="f_size_large t_align_r t_xs_align_c">Shipment Fee </p></td><td colspan="1"><p class="f_size_large color_dark t_align_r" id="amt"><button id="amoutn" data-popup="#clickMeForGettingShippingAmount" class="tr_delay_hover r_corners button_type_16 f_size_medium bg_scheme_color color_light m_xs_bottom_5">Estimate</button></p></td></tr>';

        echo '<tr><td colspan="4"><p class="f_size_large t_align_r t_xs_align_c">Applied Store Credits:</p></td><td colspan="1"><p class="f_size_large color_dark t_align_r">( - ) '.$cred.'</p></td></tr>';

        // echo '<tr><td colspan="4"><p class="fw_medium f_size_large t_align_r t_xs_align_c">Total Payable Amount:</p></td><td colspan="1"><p class="fw_medium f_size_large color_dark t_align_r">'.number_format( ( ($total + $totalTaxAmount) - $cred), 2).'</p></td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td colspan="4"><p class="fw_medium f_size_large t_align_r t_xs_align_c">Total Payable Amount:</p></td><td colspan="1"><p class="fw_medium f_size_large color_dark t_align_r">'.number_format( ( ($total + $totalTaxAmount) - $cred ), 2).'</p></td></tr>';

        echo '<tr><td colspan="4"><div id="chckOutBtn"><button class="f_right tr_delay_hover r_corners button_type_16 f_size_medium bg_scheme_color color_light m_xs_bottom_5">Proceed to Checkout</button></div></td><td colspan="1"><p class="fw_medium f_size_large color_dark t_align_r"><a href="EmptyCart.php">Empty Cart</a></p></td></tr>';
    }
}
} else {
    unset($_SESSION['sessionTotalPayable']);
    unset($_SESSION['credits']);
    unset($_SESSION['Presentation']['TotalPayableAmount']);
}
?>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])): ?>
    <p class="f_size_large t_align_r t_xs_align_c m_bottom_20">Apply Store Credits: <a href="http://www.benefitsquare.com/nbs/StoreCredits.php">Click Here</a></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</section>
<aside class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <?php require_once 'PHP_Includes/CategoriesWidget.php'; ?>
</aside>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!--markup footer-->
<?php require_once 'Includes/websiteFooter.php'; ?>

<!-- Calculate shipping pop-up -->
<div class="popup_wrap d_none" id="clickMeForGettingShippingAmount">
    <section class="popup r_corners shadow">
        <button class="bg_tr color_dark tr_all_hover text_cs_hover close f_size_large"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="custom_scrollbar">
                <h2 class="tt_uppercase color_dark m_bottom_25 t_align_c">Calculate your shipping charge</h2>
                <p class="m_bottom_25" style="color: #f00;">Note: This is will be added to your cart once you register your region on the checkout page. This is just for your estimation.</p>
                <form id="contactform">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="clearfix m_bottom_15">
                            <div class="f_left half_column">
                                <label for="cf_name" class="required d_inline_b m_bottom_5">Your Zone:</label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="m_bottom_50">
                            <select name="selectZone" id="zone" class="full_width r_corners">
                                <?php
                                $q = "SELECT * FROM shipping_zones ORDER BY ZoneName";
                                $validate->Query($q);
                                while ($row = $validate->FetchAllDatas() ) {
                                    echo '<option value="'.$row['ZoneId'].'">'.$row['ZoneName'].'</option>';
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="submit" id="check" name="btnCheckShipping" value="Done" class="full_width button_type_4 bg_light_color_2 r_corners mw_0 tr_all_hover color_dark" />
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </form>
                <div class="m_bottom_50"></div>
                <h2 class="tt_uppercase t_align_c color_dark m_bottom_25">Your Shipping Amount Is:</h2>
                <?php
                /*if (isset($_SESSION['TotalWeight']) && $_SESSION['TotalWeight'] != "") {
                    $weightAmnt = $_SESSION['TotalWeight'];
                } else {
                    $weightAmnt = 0;
                }*/
                ?>
                <h2 class="t_align_c color_dark m_bottom_25" id="totAm"><?php echo $amtWeight; ?></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What pretty URL you want for your cart?

Comment: What SEO friendly URL do you want for your cart URL `http://www.example.com/cart.php?action=add&code=ProductCode`?

Comment: It should directly go to cart.php page after adding the product to the cart

Comment: That is very vague. URL cannot add product to a cart. Do you want something like `http://www.example.com/cart/add/ProductCode` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I have tried it on my own, but the product was not added in the cart.

Answer (score 0):

Have these rules at top of your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /nbs/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /cart\.php\?action=([^\s&]+)&code=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ cart/%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^cart/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ cart.php?action=$1&code=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^product/([^/.]+)/?$ product.php?code=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^AnotherPage/([^/.]+)/?$ AnotehrPage.php?code=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Try the online version what I am doing: [link](http://www.benefitsquare.com/nbs/products.php)

Comment: What is `/nbs/` in the path?

Comment: the `nbs` is the new website for the benefitsquare.com website

Comment: wait, I'll upload the full source code of the product page and the cart.php page

Comment: PHP code wasn't needed. Just use above rules in `/nbs/.htaccess`

Comment: It is getting added.. But now I cannot see any details about the product on the cart page. What should I do ?

Comment: Did you place these rules in `/nbs/.htaccess`? I am not seeing redirection happening on your given link.