# Rookie Url Rewriting 2

Tags: php, url, rewriting

I have this rewrite rule in my htaccess script, but whenever i do a var_dump on $_GET it's empty, like the values from the url are not read in PHP.

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^index.php/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?app=$1&page=$2&category=$3 [L]
</ifModule>
```

Example of url: .../index.php/main/featured/1

How can one fix this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RewriteCond to match query string parameters in any order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307333/rewritecond-to-match-query-string-parameters-in-any-order)

Comment: Sorry, but its not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe these two conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

are not met as your URL is `/index.php/main/featured/1`. At least it did not work for me either. Can you either remove `index.php` part both from `RewriteRule` and your URL, making .htaccess:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?app=$1&page=$2&category=$3 [L]
</ifModule>
```

and navigating to URL `/main/featured/1` or if you really need the `index.php` part, then uncomment/remove these conditions:

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

and continue using `/index.php/main/featured/1` URL.