# Getting 404 on specific URL rewrite rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have learnt and written some `.htaccess` rules and some are executing perfectly. But there are few that are not getting executed and shown error or `404`

These are the rules

```
RewriteEngine on

# index.php?store=xyz (executing perfectly)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} store=([^&]+)&?
RewriteRule /?index.php$ /%1 [END,R=301]

RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?store=$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/products$ index.php?store=$1&view=products [END]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/products/([0-9]+)$ index.php?store=$1&view=products&category=$2 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/products/([0-9]+)$ index.php?store=$1&view=sales&sale=$2 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/single/([0-9]+)$ index.php?store=$1&view=single&product=$2 [END]

# index.php?store=xyz&view=products(executing perfectly)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} store=([^&]+)&?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} view=products&?
RewriteRule /?index.php$ /%1/products [END,R=301]

# index.php?store=xyz&view=products&category=123(executing perfectly)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} store=([^&]+)&?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} view=products&?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} category=([^&]+)&?
RewriteRule /?index.php$ /%1/products/%3 [END,R=301]

# index.php?store=xyz&view=sales (error 404)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} store=([^&]+)&?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} view=sales&?
RewriteRule /?index.php$ /%1/sales [END,R=301]

# index.php?store=xyz&view=sales&sale=123 (error 404)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} store=([^&]+)&?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} view=sales&?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} sale=([^&]+)&?
RewriteRule /?index.php$ /%1/sales/%3 [END,R=301]

# index.php?store=xyz&view=single&product=123(executing perfectly)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} store=([^&]+)&?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} view=single&?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} product=([^&]+)&?
RewriteRule /?index.php$ /%1/single/%3 [END,R=301]
```

Can you please tell me what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Check the code! I have written `(executing perfectly)` and `(error 404)` and their rules are written below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You redirect the client from

> index.php?store=xyz&view=single&product=123

to

> /%1/single/%3

and you have a corresponding `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/single/([0-9]+)$ index.php?store=$1&view=single&product=$2 [END]
```

---

You also redirect the client from

> index.php?store=xyz&view=sales&sale=123

to

> /%1/sales/%3

but there is *no* corresponding `RewriteRule`, only two

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/products/([0-9]+)$ index.php?store=$1&view=products&category=$2 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/products/([0-9]+)$ index.php?store=$1&view=sales&sale=$2 [END]
```

So maybe changing one of the "product" rules to "sales" fixes your immediate problem.

---

Although, you should be aware that the redirecting rules don't do, what you might think.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} store=([^&]+)&?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} view=single&?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} product=([^&]+)&?
RewriteRule /?index.php$ /%1/single/%3 [END,R=301]
```

Having three [`RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), don't correspond to `%1` and `%3` in your rewrite rule, only `%1` is valid, see [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) for an explanation

> In addition to plain text, the Substitution string can include
>
> 1. ...
> 2. back-references (%N) to *the last matched RewriteCond pattern*

To have both `%1` and `%3`, you must capture *three* parts in the last `RewriteCond`, e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} store=([^&]+)&view=(single)&product=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ...
```

See [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14308411/1741542) to [RewriteCond to match query string parameters in any order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14307333/1741542) for a solution to capture multiple parts.