# htaccess redirect based on query parameter value

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, apache2.2

My application used to do language switching using a `lang.php` file. A URL to redirect to English for `/path/to/page.php?foo=bar` would look like this:

```
/path/to/lang.php?lang=en-CA&uri=%2Fpath%2Fto%2Fpage.php%3Ffoo%3Dbar
```

Recently there has been some changes to accept a `lang` query parameter on all pages. So this URL is nicer:

```
/path/to/page.php?foo=bar&lang=en-CA
```

I'd like to be able to add a .htaccess file to all the locations that I have a `lang.php` file in order to keep the existing URL working without the `lang.php` file. Is this possible?

The RewriteRules must be completely relative to lang.php as the application is running on different hostnames and paths.

I took a stab at it based on [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26433870/404623) but this is giving me a 404:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} lang.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)uri=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule lang.php - [E=LANG_REDIR_URI:%1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} lang.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)lang=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule lang.php - [E=LANG_REDIR_LANG:%1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} lang.php$
RewriteRule . %{LANG_REDIR_URI}e [L,R=temporary]
```

The `uri` parameter may already have query parameters (as in the examble above), and the code should not make the application vulnerable to an [open redirect vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet).

Different cases:

- URI with query string, lang first: `/foo/bar/lang.php?lang=en-CA&uri=%2Ffoo%2Fbar%2Fpage.php%3Fid%3D123` should redirect to `/foo/bar/page.php?id=123&lang=en-CA`
- URI without query string, lang first: `/foo/bar/lang.php?lang=en-CA&uri=%2Ffoo%2Fbar%2Fpage.php` should redirect to `/foo/bar/page.php?lang=en-CA`
- URI with query string, uri first: `/foo/bar/lang.php?uri=%2Ffoo%2Fbar%2Fpage.php%3Fid%3D123&lang=en-CA` should redirect to `/foo/bar/page.php?id=123&lang=en-CA`
- URI without query string, uri first: `/foo/bar/lang.php?uri=%2Ffoo%2Fbar%2Fpage.php&lang=en-CA` should redirect to `/foo/bar/page.php?lang=en-CA`

The order of the query parameters do not matter in the redirect *target*.

**UPDATE**

After the initial answer provided at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45732670/404623, I've tried the following .htaccess rules:

```
# This only works for uri values without query strings

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(lang=[^&]+)&uri=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule lang\.php$ /%2\?%1 [L,NE,R=temporary]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^uri=([^&]+)&(lang=[^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule lang\.php$ /%1\?%2 [L,NE,R=temporary]

# This only works for uri values with query strings

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(lang=[^&]+)&uri=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule lang\.php$ /%2&%1? [L,NE,R=temporary]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^uri=([^&]+)&(lang=[^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule lang\.php$ /%1&%2? [L,NE,R=temporary]
```

Comment: `%2F` is not allowed in Apache unless you have used `AllowEncodedSlashes` in Apache server config.

Comment: @anubhava I just enabled that on my dev environment and I'm still getting a 404

Answer (score 2):

You can use this rule in your site root .htaccess just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteEngine On

# uri with query string    
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     (?:^|&)(lang=[^&]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %1##%{QUERY_STRING} (.*)##(?:.*&)?uri=([^?]+)(?:\?|%3F)([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule lang\.php$ /%2?%1&%3 [L,NE,R=302]

# uri without query string    
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     (?:^|&)(lang=[^&]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %1##%{QUERY_STRING} (.*)##(?:.*&)?uri=([^?]+) [NC]
RewriteRule lang\.php$ /%2?%1 [L,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to change the rule use a question mark in the middle for it to work, like this: `RewriteRule lang\.php$ /%2\?%1 [L,NE,R=temporary]`.

Comment: Actually upon further testing I discovered that the `?` in the middle only works for URLs without query parameters whereas the `&` in the middle only works for URLs with query parameters. Is there a way to satisfy both cases? Also the order isn't guaranteed so I duplicated it with the uri first in order to handle that. I hope I don't have to duplicate all of it to handle with and without query params

Comment: ok I can tweak these rules further. But you should update question with your existing .htaccess that shows these new set of rules. Also please include a sample URL for each rule so that I can test rules after modifying.

Comment: I have modified my question to add sample URLs as well as my attempts using the rule in your solution.

Comment: Ok good update. So URI with query parameters can be: `/path/to/lang.php?lang=en-CA&uri=%2Fpath%2Fto%2Fpage.php%3Ffoo%3Dbar` and without can be this `/path/to/lang.php?lang=en-CA&uri=%2Fpath%2Fto%2Fpage.php` right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The order of the query parameters might be different (as described).