# .htaccess rewrite rule for affiliate links

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've many links of this type:

```
https://example.com/?redirectTo=G04BIQ8LGG&redirect_prodid=xyz-G04BIQ8LGG
```

I need to redirect to amazon affiliate link:

```
https://www.amazon.com/dp/G04BIQ8LGG?tag=mytag-21&linkCode=ogi&th=1&psc=1
```

The only part to take from old url is the product code (ex.**G04BIQ8LGG**)

Someone can help me with .htaccess rule and regex?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [htaccess redirect based on query parameter value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45678949/htaccess-redirect-based-on-query-parameter-value)

Comment: unfortunately no, I'm not very good with regex. That's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: So, the query string `tag=mytag-21&linkCode=ogi&th=1&psc=1` is fixed for every _product code_?

Comment: yes it's fixed for all products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> unfortunately no, I'm not very good with regex.

The regex is very similar as in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45678949/htaccess-redirect-based-on-query-parameter-value). However, the required mod_rewrite directives themselves are much simpler in this case.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^redirectTo=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.amazon.com/dp/%1?tag=mytag-21&linkCode=ogi&th=1&psc=1 [NE,R=302,L]
```

I've anchored the `redirectTo` URL parameter to the start of the query string, since that is how it appears in your example. In the *linked question*, the URL parameter can appear anywhere in the query string since that would seem to have been a requirement in that question.

Since the URL parameter value is used in the URL-path of the redirected URL, the `NE` (`noescape`) flag is required to prevent a %-encoded URL param value being doubly encoded in the resulting redirect. (Although this is not an issue if this URL param value is never %-encoded - it doesn't necessarily look as if it would be.)